# I want to display Size Attribute value list beside Size using laravel

Tags: database, laravel

For Attribute i can make two table
1 is **`attributes`** and another is **`attribute_values`**

For `attributes` **table**

```html
Schema::create('attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('attributeName')->unique();
      $table->timestamps();
  });
```

For `attribute_values` **table**

```html
Schema::create('attribute_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('attributeId');
    $table->string('value')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to show like:

Under **Size**: L, S, M, XL etc

Under **Color**: Red, Green etc

What is the query ? and how can i apply ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` is hasMany relationship

```
$attributes = Attribute::with('values')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

In the view

```
@foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    {{ $attribute->values->pluck('value')->join(', ') }}
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join

Comment: I can understand, But i am new in laravel. I can't apply this in my code.